# How can I share file in Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have three M.2 solid state drives and a hard disk drive.

My plan is intalling Windows 11, Ubuntu 20.04, Arch-Linux systems respectively in the three SSD and restoring some important files in the hard disk.

But I am puzzled about how to read and edit the files in the hard disk in all three systems.

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work...

Comment: Use one of the cloud sync tools?

Comment: As the files are important, perhaps an external file server with regular backups would be a good place to keep them. An external file server would be visible to all three systems.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use WSL2 on Windows to install Ubuntu and use it and you can access all you Ubuntu file from this PC on Windows and install gui and us it as normal Ubuntu on your windows 11
2. Dual boot windows 11, ubuntu and Arch-Linux and you can easily access you data from M.2/SSD/HDD

Bellow images show easily you can access you data from anther disk drive connected on you machine

[image]

[image: This screenshot show how easily you can access you data from anther disk drive connected on you machine]